# PHP Composer issue None of the 0 stable version(s) of Composer matches your PHP

Tags: php, centos, composer-php, centos6

Hi i m trying to install php composer in my vps using this command but i get as error

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/versions): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in - on line 770
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in - on line 516

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in - on line 516
None of the 0 stable version(s) of Composer matches your PHP version (5.3.3 / ID: 50303)
```

my os is CentOS release 6.8

php PHP 5.3.3

Comment: You need to upgrade PHP. 5.6 would be the least that you would want.

Comment: how could i do it i try with yum update but without any resulta

Comment: Are outgoing connections from your VPS filtered by your provider? Can you ping other hosts?

Comment: yeah i could ping on other hosts but when i write yum update i get 
No Packages marked for Update

Comment: @JayBlanchard i updated my php version but the same message displayed